# What is a single word for "Not revealing too much information at the first glance of another onlooking person"?

Tags: single-word-requests

> **Situation:**
>   We are making an app that logs *sensitive* health data.

The first screen of the app shows a color-coded summary of the past health data, but is intended to be made in such a way that if any onlooker looks at the app's user's screen, the onlooker will not be able to guess what the app is about (especially because the user would really warrant privacy).

I'm currently thinking of "obscure", "imperceptible", "indiscernible", "inconspicuous".

Comment: That is a terrible idea for a user interface.

Comment: Terrible and *in the way you describe it* impossible.
*As you describe it* the code would be meaningful to all users, but no-one else, yes? What happens when a user leaves? Do you change the code, or accept an ex-user not just guessing but knowing full well what the app is about?
What did your dictionaries and search engines leave unclear about *obscure, imperceptible, indiscernible* or *inconspicuous*? None of those approaches any distinction between users and onlookers.
What dictionary or search engine suggested *warrant*?
Further, try making a color-coded summary of health data…

Comment: Just to make the two of you aware, the health data is the adherence of HIV patients to their medications for that month. It is a medical research being done on how apps along with motion sensors in pill bottles can help track medication consumption so as to make the lives of these patients easier. However, neither of you two provided any useful inputs via your comments on the original question on how I would describe it correctly. Anyway, I was satisfied with what results I found.

Answer (score 1):

Consider *circumspect* (see MW)  (careful, prudent)

But also consider that any graph or display that shows up on an app that's used by quite a few people is going to be recognized.  Other people with Garmin devices, e.g., know what Garmin displays look like.  People have gotten good at learning such things quickly.

Answer (score 0):

There is a term **obfuscation software** which is not *quite* what you are looking for, but very close.

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Obfuscation_(software))

> obfuscation is the deliberate act of creating source or machine code that is difficult for humans to understand

The term refers to obfuscated source or machine code rather than the screen display but the result is the same. It is designed not to mislead but to merely present an appearance that is meaningless.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I think "obfuscation" might not be the best word for the context. It might be perfect to describe ProGuard though!

Answer (score 0):

In order to draw no attention, the display should be **featureless**.

[Oxford English Dictionary](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/68851?redirectedFrom=featureless#eid) (requires subscription)

> Featureless : Without any prominent mark or point of interest; uninteresting.

Comment: Ah! How I wish it could've worked. But an app's main screen being "featureless" would maybe undermine it's usefulness.

Comment: Your 'obfuscation' answer is much better